# Do THIS: only if between this timeframe

Tags: php, date, time

what I am trying to do with PHP is something I am sure is simple but cannot figure it out. What I need help with is this:

- We have a Live Chat feature on our website that is turned on & off manually each day between 9am-6pm
- What I would like is to be able to have the chat turned on & off based on the time. If the time is between 9am-6pm I would like the chat to be turned on. However, if the current time is not between that timeframe, I would like the Live Chat to be turned off.

All I need help with is the time functionality part. I just do not know how to put together the correct functions/if/else statements. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$c_time = mktime();
$open = strtotime('Today 8am');
$close = strtotime('Today 5pm');

if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close) {
    echo 'Chat open.';
} else {
    echo 'Chat closed.';
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/2QXXF8Lo (Remember this server may be in another timezone.)

I suppose technically all you need is:

```
$open = strtotime('8am');
$close = strtotime('5pm');
```

http://codepad.org/e0xjCuji